# Excel: Random select within table that meets two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Here is an example of my data:

```
Name:        Office:   Years:

John Smith   Canada      1

Bob Smith    Canada      1

Jake Smith   Canada      1

Sarah Smith  Canada      1
```

On another sheet I want to output a random name based upon Office and Years. As I drag the formula down I want it to give a different name every time (this is where I'm stuck). I have tried several formulas and this is the closest.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$436,MATCH(SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$436&$F$2:$F$436=$H$3&$I$3,$G$2:$G$436),1),$G$2:$G$436,0))
```

Column B = Name Column D=Office Column  F=Years then H3 and I3  are my lookup values

column G is a set of random numbers = rand()

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to put the randomization in the formula itself.  You could always put this in another column if you want.

Column A is name
Column B is office
Column C is year

Cell G2 is the office you are interested in
Cell G3 is the year you are interested in

> `=INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$7=G2,IF($C$2:$C$7=G3,ROW($A$2:$A$7),0),0), RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS(B:B,G2,C:C,G3))))`

This is an array formula and needs to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It works by creating an array that has the row numbers (if criteria is matched) or zero if it doesn't.  Then it takes the *n*th largest value,
where *n* is a random number between 1 and the number of rows that match the criteria.

Comment: I don't think that will give "a different name every time" as per the requirement - if RANDBETWWEN returns the same number you'll get a repeated name - see my answer for a way to do that

Comment: Thats true. I was working off the "output a random name by office and year" and kind of forgot the rest of it. I will leave the answer up as I think it is still a useful formula that is similar in nature to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return names in A2 down (where A1 is a header or blank) then use this array formula in A2

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$436,SMALL(IF(($D$2:$D$436=$H$3)*($F$2:$F$436=$I$3)*(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,$B$2:$B$436)=0),ROW($B$2:$B$436)-ROW($B$2)+1),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM(($D$2:$D$436=$H$3)*($F$2:$F$436=$I$3)*(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,$B$2:$B$436)=0)))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> and copy down - change the `A$1:A1` range in the `COUNTIF` functions to match the cell above your start cell.

Note: - you don't need a column of random numbers with this method